# Now and Next TV Programme Information SQL Query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, schedule

My table is a list of Scheduled TV Programmes for multiple days and channels.

```
SELECT * FROM [Scheduled_Programmes]

Channel   Date          Time     Title
1         2012-09-19    06:00    Family Guy
2         2012-09-19    06:01    CSI Miami
3         2012-09-19    06:20    News
1         2012-09-19    06:30    Heroes
2         2012-09-19    07:01    Spiderman
3         2012-09-19    06:40    Batman
1         2012-09-19    07:30    Micky Mouse
2         2012-09-19    07:31    CSI New York
3         2012-09-19    07:10    Friends
1         2012-09-19    07:55    The Wire
2         2012-09-19    08:00    Dodgeball
3         2012-09-19    07:35    Gossip Girl
```

The result set I'm trying to create is What's on Now and What's on Next.

```
Let's assume the current datetime is (D/M/Y HH:MM) 19/09/2012 07:15
```

So something like:

```
          Channel 1     Channel 2       Channel 3
NOW       Heroes        Spiderman       Friends  
NEXT      Micky Mous    CSI New York    Gossip Girl
```

I've been racking my brain for the best way to do this without having to hard code an individual query for each channel. I think I've got the the overthinking it stage now
 so it would be great if someone can point me in the right direction.

Thanks

PS: If it makes a difference I'm on Microsoft SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This really seems like something you would let your GIU format and pivot but here's my go at it.

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT X.Status, X.Channel, X.Title FROM (
        SELECT 'NOW' as Status, Channel, Title, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Channel ORDER BY Time DESC) RANKED FROM Sceduled_Programs SP
        WHERE DateTime <= '7:15') X
        WHERE X.RANKED = 1
    ) A
    UNION ALL
        SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT Y.Status, Y.Channel, Y.Title FROM (
        SELECT 'NEXT' as Status, Channel, Title, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Channel ORDER BY Time ASC) RANKED FROM Sceduled_Programs SP
        WHERE DateTime > '7:15') Y
        WHERE Y.RANKED = 1
    ) B
) DataToPivot
PIVOT (MAX(Title) FOR Channel IN ([1], [2], [3])) AS PivotTable
```

Edit:
I'm only using time here but just add date. You should really consider combining the date and time columns.

Edit2:
To add date just replace the time compare with this. Should even work over date boundaries.

```
WHERE CAST(Date AS DATETIME) + CAST(Time AS DATETIME) > '19/09/2012 07:15'
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you so much! I do have a combined date/time column however that is for the "real" transmission time, not the TV guide style time/date I'm using here. (eg: 18:00:00 vs 18:02:13) Also, I agree that some of this could be done in the GUI, but I knew it could be done in SQL and it was driving me mad. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here is the [SQLFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a80ef/31). **This query also works well if a program starts in the previous day and ends in the current or starts in the current and ends in the next day** (for NOW and NEXT results).

For current date just replace `cast('09/19/2012 07:15' as datetime)` with the `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`:

```
with T as 
(select channel, title, 
       (date+cast(Time as datetime )) as D_Time 
       from Scheduled_Programmes
)

select nn,
   max(CASE when channel=1 then Title end) as Chanel1, 
   max(CASE when channel=2 then Title end) as Chanel2,
   max(CASE when channel=3 then Title end) as Chanel3


from
(
select 'NOW' nn,Channel,Title,D_time,
    row_number() over (PARTITION by channel 
                      order by D_time desc) rn 
    from T
    where D_time<=cast('09/19/2012 07:15' as datetime)
union
select 'NEXT'nn,Channel,Title,D_time,
     row_number() over (PARTITION by channel 
                        order by D_time asc) rn 
     from T
     where D_time>cast('09/19/2012 07:15' as datetime)
) ATable where rn=1
group by nn
order by nn desc;
```

Comment: Magnuses example above can't handle the 'next' programme if it is on the date boundary as I've implemented it so will tinker further and consult your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct Channel
, (
select top 2 Title from 
        (
         select Title
         from [Scheduled_Programmes] s
         where s.Channel = o.Channel
         and Date >='2012-09-19' and Time >='07:15' 
         group by Channel
         order by Date, Time desc
        ) x
) as Prog
from [Scheduled_Programmes] o
```

I have not tried it (due to unavailability of SQL Server at this point ), but this should work.

Comment: You can't `select top 2` in scalar context

Comment: Thanks, it also didn't like the order by with out containing Title in some kind of aggregate.

Answer (score 0):

To get the data and cross-tab it use the following. You can rename the channel columns in the first select, but you do have to specify the valid channels in the pivot list.

N.b. The code could be simplified by combining the date and time fields to a single datetime field.

```
declare @current_date datetime = '20120919 07:15'

select *
from (
  select whenon, a1.channel, title from (
  select a.channel, MAX(CAST(Date AS DATETIME) + CAST(Time AS DATETIME)) as DateTime, 'now' as whenon
  from Scheduled_Programmes a
  join (
    select channel, MIN(CAST(Date AS DATETIME) + CAST(Time AS DATETIME)) as NextTime
    from Scheduled_Programmes 
    where CAST(Date AS DATETIME) + CAST(Time AS DATETIME) > @current_date
    group by channel
  ) b on a.channel = b.channel and CAST(Date AS DATETIME) + CAST(Time AS DATETIME) < NextTime
  group by a.channel
  union
  select channel, MIN(CAST(Date AS DATETIME) + CAST(Time AS DATETIME)), 'next' from Scheduled_Programmes where CAST(Date AS DATETIME) + CAST(Time AS DATETIME) > @current_date
  group by channel

  ) a1
  join Scheduled_Programmes b1 on a1.channel = b1.channel and a1.DateTime = CAST(Date AS DATETIME) + CAST(Time AS DATETIME)
) sub
pivot (max(title) for channel in ([1], [2], [3])) pivottable
order by whenon desc
```

Comment: Cheers, this works in all cases just looks a bit ugly because I did it without CTE or RANK() for some reason!

Answer (score 0):

Another possible option - calculate the time difference & fetch the smallest +ve value (next) and smallest -ve value (now) - assumes DATE & TIME type fields, also returns minutes since start/until start.

```
;with T(Channel, Date, Time, Title, delta) as (
select 
    *,
    datediff(minute, '19 sep 2012 07:15:00', dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, date), cast(time as datetime2)))
from 
    Scheduled_Programmes
)
select 
case when T.delta >= 0 then 'Next' else 'Now' end,
T.* 
from T
inner join (
    select
        channel,
        min(case when delta > 0 then delta end) as starts_in,
        max(case when delta < 0 then delta end) as started
    from t
    group by channel
) T2
    on T.Channel = T2.Channel and (t.delta = T2.starts_in or t.delta=T2.started)
order by Channel, delta
```